# Count values in row where first column is value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to create a formula that counts the times the column contains "blue" when the name is "Anna"

In this example that would be a total of 3.

| Anna | Krijn | Fieke | Anna | Krijn | Fieke |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| blue | green | blue | green | blue | green |
| green | blue | green | blue | green | blue |
| blue | green | blue | green | blue | green |

I've tried COUNTIFS, but couldn't get it to work because the name appears multiple times in the first row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the setup in the screenshot should be helpful in what the formula is aiming at:

```
=COUNTIF(IFERROR(FILTER({A2:F},A1:F1=H2)),I2)
```

or to place  it more directly:

```
=COUNTIF(IFERROR(FILTER({A2:F},A1:F1="Anna")),"blue")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(FILTER(A31:F; A30:F30="Anna")="blue")
```

[image]